# How to find whether the AWS lambda function is in active mode or in sleep mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Wonder is there any way to find out whether my lambda function is running any script at this moment or not?

Comment: check cloudwatch?

Comment: That's the one way. But I want to find that out programmatically.

Comment: you can access cloudwatch programmatically using sdk or cli. you can also set up alarms in cloudwatch or change lambda code to send notification when it is running.